# Weighting the seaborn histplot probabilities when viewing multiple distributions

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, distribution

I am plotting four distributions using seaborn histplot. I can view the bin probability for each distribution but would like to reweight these probabilities so the total sum of probabilities across ALL distributions = 1 (not the sum of probabilities for EACH distribution).

I can see that there are 'weights' parameters but I think that applies to each data point rather than the seaborn-calculated bin probability. Is there a way to just have seaborn multiply by a factor each histogram bin probabilities that it calculates. So for the four distributions, to multiple the first by 0.4, and the other three by 0.2? Code to produce the four series below:

```
from scipy.stats import skewnorm
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd


rdata = pd.DataFrame()
np.random.seed(2022)  # so the distribution will be the same each time
rdata['Recession'] = skewnorm.rvs(1, loc=3000, scale=400, size=100000)
rdata['Recovery'] = skewnorm.rvs(0, loc=3300, scale=300, size=100000)
rdata['Expansion'] = skewnorm.rvs(-1, loc=3800, scale=200, size=100000)
rdata['Slowdown'] = skewnorm.rvs(-3, loc=3600, scale=250, size=100000)

sn.histplot(rdata, bins=50, stat='probability', cumulative=False, kde=True)
```

[image]

Comment: From the docs: _**common_norm : bool If True and using a normalized statistic, the normalization will apply over the full dataset. Otherwise, normalize each histogram independently.**_ The default is `True`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't want four distributions that each sum to 1 though. What I want is the four distributions to total 1 (so common_norm=True) but where I can apply weightings to each distribution. So I only want to display 40% of the first distribution probabilities and 20% of each of the other distribution probabilities. So the total probability is still 100% but not evenly spread across the distributions. Can this be done using 'weights' or does that apply to every source data point?